# htaccess redirect cirtain requests to a different subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I recently upgraded my website, changed the underlying system, and pushed the old content onto a subdomain.

I want the google indexed URLs to the old content to still work, so I added a rewrite rule to the main htaccess that I thought would redirect using looking for the old 2015 posts, but it doesn't appear to be working.

I have added the rule to the top of CraftCMS's default htaccess, which is at the root of my domain.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/2015(/.*)?$ http://old.keithcod.es/2015$1 [R=301,L]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I clarify, I'm trying to redirect all traffic from `/2015/*` to `old.keithcod.es/2015/*`

Comment: change your first rule this: `RewriteRule ^/?2015(/.*)?$ http://old.keithcod.es/$0 [R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: @anubhava Still does not appear to be working, example url: http://keithcod.es/2015/11/07/eagle-4-port-usb-hub-fe1-1s/  it seems like it's skipping right past that rule and going onto the ones under it. I also made sure to purge my server and browser cache to ensure neither was caching the page.

Comment: Providing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is removed (or made optional, as in anubhava's suggestion) then this "should" work for the above URL. Are you sure the directives that follow are being processed? Check the `p` parameter in your script. Try a simple "temporary" redirect.